# Writing a for loop as a list comprehension, returning unexpected values?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

if I feed this function:

```
def even(numbers):
    numbers =  [i for i in range(len (numbers)) if i % 2 == 0]
```

These numbers:

```
even([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

I get `[0,2,4]`. Where does the 0 come from?

Comment: Try this - `[i for i in numbers if i % 2 == 0]`. You are iterating the numbers in the index range rather than the value it self.

Comment: numbers =  [i for i in numbers if i % 2 == 0]
    print(numbers), this worked perfectly thank you

Comment: Yep. That should work.To know why, check out the nicely explained answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You loop over a *`range()` call*. This produces integers between 0 and the `len(numbers)` value you passed in:

```
>>> numbers = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> [i for i in range(len(numbers))]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Since this range started at `0` and `0` is considered even, you get that included in the result. Your `numbers` list has length 5, so the `range()` counts from 0 through to 4 (the end value is never included in the resulting range).

If you wanted to loop over `numbers` itself, don't use `range()`:

```
[i for i in numbers if i % 2 == 0]
```

Python `for` loops are [Foreach loop constructs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop); they can loop directly over a list, there is no need to generate indices.

Answer (score 1):

The function `range` produces values from `0` to `N` (not including `N`).

So the call to

```
range(len (numbers))
```

will produce values `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

If your intention is to filter out the odd numbers, you can modify your function to

```
def even(numbers):
    return [i for i in numbers if i%2 == 0]

>>> even([5,4,3,2,1])
[4, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

`range()` generates numbers from 0 to n by default, where n is the argument value passed. You passed `len([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])` which evaluates to `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing range(len(numbers)) will iterate the loop for "the size of the list" times starting with 0 regardless of what is inside the list. Hence change it to following:

```
def even(numbers):
    numbers =  [i for i in numbers if i % 2 == 0]
    return numbers
print(even([5,4,3,2,1]))
```